# code coverage for FOR loop in Test class

Tags: for

Unable to cover the code coverage from if condition inside for loop.

```
public class cwrapper{
    apply__c g = new apply__c();
    selected = false;

    public cwrapper(apply__c a, boolean selected){
        a = g;
        selected = true;
    }

}

// for loop
for(cWrapper wrp : cwrapperlist){
    if(wrp.selected ){
        mapRecords.put(wrp.g.id, wrp);
    }
    if(finwrp.selected  == false && mapRecords.containsKey(wrp.g.id)){
        mapRecords.remove(wrp.g.id);
    }
}
```

How to cover from if condition inside forloop in test class.

Comment: should your loop be inside the method ?call that method.

Comment: its a private method which is called in another method.I have called public method  but the coverage has been done till for loop only ,It is not entering for loop,I want whole thing to be covered.

Comment: I move comment to answer because the format is better there.

Comment: `cwrapperlist` will be empty thats why for loop is not getting covered. Check from where `cwrapperlist` is populated.

Answer (score 0):

If your method is private, use @TestVisible so it will be reachable by test class.

```
// Private method
    @TestVisible private static void updateRecord(String name) {
        // Do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe control is not entering the for loop, because your `cwrapperlist` is empty, please make sure you call the correct code to populate this list before trying to cover the for loop and inside.

Comment: Please stop adding *hope this helps* to every answer. It's implicit in the fact you are posting an answer that you hope it will help. SFSE is not a forum, but rather a terse Q&A site.

Comment: sure, will take care now onwards!

Comment: @NitishSinghal My wrapperlist is having all the required values .....checked it with system.assert.but it is not entering the for loop

Comment: @anjali If the line `for(cWrapper wrp : cwrapperlist){` is covered but the contents between the braces aren't, it means that Salesforce has looked at the `for` loop but because the collection is empty, it's got nothing to do so skips it. It does sound like your collection is empty.

Comment: @DanJones - when I checked with system.assertequals(null,actual) - test class is failing because actual has values means wrapperlist has values . Is it right?